# Shadow "Cast Only" option in Blender 2.8 seems to be missing

Tags: shadows

I'm using Blender 2.82 and Cycles. I've got an object that I want to be invisible, but still cast a shadow.

I've done a fair bit of Googling, and as far as I can tell the ["Cast Only" shadow option](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/materials/properties/shadows.html) that used to exist in Blender 2.7 and earlier, no longer exists. I checked material properties and object properties. It's missing from the manual. If I uncheck "Show in Viewports/Renders", the shadow disappears too.

I realize there are some complex workflows described in other threads about how to accomplish this, but I was wondering if there's some obvious way to do it like before, that I'm missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object Properties/Visibility/Ray Visibility/Camera on/off
[image]

Comment: I think that was the one option I didn't try. Thanks!